# how to center an image with background attachment

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this problem that when inserting the fixed effect it only shows half of the image, I want to see the whole image on the right side while I am adapting it to a mobile device

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
   margin: 200px 0;
   background: #ccc;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.content:nth-child(2) {
   background: url(http://imgfz.com/i/sPTEXhi.png) no-repeat fixed #ccc;
   background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-size: contain;
   height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
     <h2>Title Website<h2>
     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
     adipisicing elit. In,sequi.
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
   margin: 200px 0;
   background: #ccc;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.content:nth-child(2) {
   background: url(http://imgfz.com/i/sPTEXhi.png) no-repeat fixed #ccc;
   background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
   height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
     <h2>Title Website<h2>
     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
     adipisicing elit. In,sequi.
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove fixed and use background-size:

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
   margin: 200px 0;
   background: #ccc;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.content:nth-child(2) {
   background: url(http://imgfz.com/i/sPTEXhi.png) no-repeat #ccc;
   background-position: 100% 100%;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
     <h2>Title Website<h2>
     <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
     adipisicing elit. In,sequi.
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```